# Why explicit string conversion is required in .format method in python is required?

Tags: python, numpy

The following code is giving TypeError.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=False).split(range(25))

print('{} {:^61} {}'.format('Iteration','Training set observations','Testing set observations'))
for iteration, data in enumerate(kf, start=3):
    print('{:^9} {} {:^25}'.format(iteration, data[0], data[1]))
```

> TypeError: unsupported format string passed to
>   numpy.ndarray.**format**

The code gives correct output when we use `str(data[1])`

Why is this explicit string conversion required ?

Comment: because that is what the authors of `str.format` decided.

Comment: but why not with data[0], it works fine with data[0].

Comment: What? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From, e.g., https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language:

> A general convention is that an empty format string (`""`) produces the same result as if you had called `str()` on the value. A non-empty format string typically modifies the result.

So, when `:^25` is matched to `data[1]`, it calls the `__format__()` method of `data[1]` object, which is a `numpy.ndarray`. These objects follow Python's `list` behavior of raising a `TypeError` when format string is non-empty. An empty format string results in `str()` being called on `data[0]` (in your example) so that would work. A non-empty format string (i.e., `:^25` for `data[1]`) fails on lists in Python because a standard list in Python can be a collection of heterogenous objects and therefore *a single* format specification might not work for a list like this one: `[1, 2.3, 'four']`. `numpy` simply follows the same convention.

---

Also see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5543 for an open issue on `numpy`'s `GitHub` page. It seems that issue is concerned about the same issue that you mention in your post.